# NVIDIA graphics card not working on Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a NVIDIA GeForce 940MX graphics card, and I've installed Linux Mint 18 on this laptop. If I switch to this card in the driver manager, Mint crashes. How am I to go about using this card?

Diver Manager Screenshot:

[image]

I also keep getting this "`No hardware acceleration` notification:
`Cinnamon is currently running without video hardware acceleration and, as a result, you may observe much higher than normal CPU usage.`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have installed latest driver can you please share crashlog or dmesg just after you use change use the graphics card.
As per [this](https://mintguide.org/system/562-install-the-nvidia-driver-361-on-linux-mint.html) it should work directly after you install driver.

so I don't see a problem. and both errors are pretty normal when you don't select graphics card.

So waiting for message log

Comment: How do I view to crashlog/dmesg?

Comment: open terminal and type dmesg

Comment: The NVIDIA page keeps asking me to install Java. But I already have it installed. `java -version` yeilds this:
`openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)`
Also, the dmesg log outputs this error:
`[    0.991258] checking generic (b0000000 7f0000) vs hw (d0000000 2000000)
[    0.991268] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    0.991301] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (1180d0a2)`

Comment: @Mihir, according to the dmesg log you have provided. It points out that drivers are not installed properly or card is not inserted properly. Please check hardware connection and if possible check it with other OS if this card is working properly. Also check with this command    `lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' `   and send the output this checks which are pci devices connected. and also check this command `lsmod` to check which of the drivers currently loaded

Comment: According to this image you sent It is clear that Graphics card is not installed (software / hardware) properly. and second command is for to check which drivers are used currently to check whether driver is invoked or not ?

Comment: The card is working on Windows, which means it's not installed properly on Mint. How do I go about installing it properly?

Comment: Ok so first use [this link](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/367.27/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run) to download run file and use  `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run` to run the file let me know if this works. if still doesn't work post dmesg log to figure out issue

Comment: I installed it. Now I'm not able to do anything, the OS keeps on crashing. In the Driver Manager, there's a 3rd item 'Manually installed driver', and I'm not even able to switch back to the original one.

Comment: can you please tell me exact steps you did ? also any errors you ignored while installing ? and for your solution in grub select second option rescue mode. try it and let me know.

Comment: also in case you can get to prompt send me out put of following command `inxi -Fxz` this is system info mentioning which hardware is using which driver. so it will be easy to debug also send dmesg output in case of crash. And worst case if you unanble to login via gui try use CTRL + ALT + F1 key to go to command prompt try logging in via cmd line and send out output and error log

Comment: dmseg log 1: https://s28.postimg.org/5xto3uxfx/IMAG0249.jpg; log 2: https://s28.postimg.org/5nm5kiitp/IMAG0251.jpg; inxi -Fxz: https://s28.postimg.org/4wtfeqggd/IMAG0250.jpg

Comment: Hi mihir strange thing is it is showing in log3 but sees not initialised properly in first two logs. So we first try to solve them first So suggested solutions will be try to boot with modified bootargs(you will get it in google how to boot with changed args in grub) `pci=nomsi`  check if this solves the issue.

Comment: @MihirRana I have made a mistake while providing a driver I have mistakenly provided wring version which does not support the graphics card. You can use [this](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/112992) it will be NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.26.run run this and let me know. you can also check supported devices does show 940MX which didn't last time. I am pretty sure this will solve the issue.

Comment: I got this error: `"The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!"`. But I was able to fix it and install the driver. However, mint is still crashing.

Comment: hi Mihir two questions :  1) did you remove previous driver ? 2) can you provide some info more than its crashing like previous(remember providing more info increases chances of your answer to get answered)

Comment: 1. No, I have not removed the previous driver. 2. The OS keeps on crashing and asks me to either restart it or continue. If I choose to continue, it goes into this very basic gui setting. However, at the time of installation the driver installed successfully, or so it says at least.

Comment: Hi mihir first thing is to remove both drivers and install correct driver. can you elaborate crash log and dmesg .